# EBP - API in Python - get access token

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, openid

I would like to get data via the API of EBP, unfortunately I can not receive my access token ... I develop in python and I tried everything. Unfortunately EBP does not support and their documentation is more than shaky

Would someone have an idea or a sample to help me?

PS: It's OAuth2.0 and OpenId for authentification

here is the EBP doc : `[https://developpeurs-storage.ebp.com][1]`